# PushSharp: Unable to write data to the transport connection

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I'm using PushSharp 4.0.10 to send iOS push notifications but I recently noticed that the console application hosting the broker to queue notifications to around 18,000 device tokens crashes after sending some notifications getting this error message:

> [ERROR] APNS-CLIENT[1]: Send Batch Error: Batch ID=4, Err
>   or=System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport
>   connection: An e xisting connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ---> System.Net.Socke ts.SocketException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote hos t    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndSend(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Net.Security._SslStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at
>   System.IO.Stream.<>c__DisplayClass0.b__17(Stream
>   strea m, IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrimPromise`1.Complete(TInst
>   ance thisRef, Func`3 endMethod, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean
>   requiresSynchr onization)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
>   ification(Task task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>
>   at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.<SendBatch>d__21.MoveNext()
>   2016-04-07 12:09:52.PM [ERROR] APNS-Client[1]: Reader Exception:
>   System.IO.IOExc eption: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An established connec tion was aborted by the software in
>   your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.S ocketException: An
>   established connection was aborted by the software in your ho st
>   machine    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, In t32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    --- End
>   of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, In t32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Net.FixedSizeReader.StartReading()    at
>   System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offse t, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, I nt32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, In t32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security._SslStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int3 2 count, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32  count, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)    at
>   System.IO.Stream.<>c__DisplayClass0.<BeginEndReadAsync>b__7(Stream
>   stream,  ReadWriteParameters args, AsyncCallback callback, Object
>   state)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrim[TInstance,TArgs](TInsta
>   nce thisRef, TArgs args, Func`5 beginMethod, Func`3 endMethod)    at
>   System.IO.Stream.BeginEndReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   coun t)    at System.IO.Stream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 count, Cance llationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.IO.Stream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>   at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.d__23.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
>   ification(Task task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.d__21.MoveNext()
>   2016-04-07 12:09:59.PM [ERROR] APNS-CLIENT[1]: Send Batch Error: Batch
>   ID=6, Err or=System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set
>   to an instance of an object.    at
>   PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.createBatch(List`1 toSend)    at
>   PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.d__21.MoveNext()
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.    at
>   PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.d__21.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNot
>   ification(Task task)    at
>   PushSharp.Apple.ApnsConnection.<<-ctor>b__1_0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c__DisplayClass2.
>   b__5(Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object
>   sta te)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionCo ntext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, C ontextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWor
>   kItem.ExecuteWorkItem()    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

Any idea why this happens? Is this related to concurrent connections? If yes, doesn't PushSharp handle this itself?